# Copying a file in sftp with jsch library

Tags: java, ssh, sftp, jsch

```
import com.jcraft.jsch.*;

public class App {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    Session session = null;
    try {
        session = jsch.getSession("Username", "Host", PORT NO);
        session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setPassword("Password");
        session.connect();

        Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
        channel.connect();
        ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) channel;

        sftpChannel.get("remotefile.txt", "localfile.txt");
        sftpChannel.exit();
        session.disconnect();
    } catch (JSchException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    } catch (SftpException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I dont want this          sftpChannel.get("remotefile.txt", "localfile.txt");

I just want to create two methods 
1)to copy the file from remote location to local system
2)to remove the copied file in an sftp connection

Can anyone help..

Answer (score 16):

Do a copy of the remote file and then delete it

```
ChannelSftp.get("remotefile.txt", "localfile.txt");
ChannelSftp.rm("remotefile.txt")
```

Comment: When i do a `c.get(fsrc, fdest)` I see the remote file is getting deleted... what can be wrong?