# keep folder structure after drag and drop upload in java

Tags: java, file-upload, applet, directory

i ve written a drag and drop applet that uploads files to an ftp server, problem is, the directory tree is lost after the upload, is there a way to keep the tree structure of the folder that is uploaded and recreate this structure on the ftp site, eg. c:\temp\new on local becomes \www\uploads\temp\new on the ftp server
thanks

below is a sample of the method resposible for the upload

```
public void showDir(File file) throws IOException {
     uploadClass sender = new uploadClass();
     text.append( file.getCanonicalPath() + "\n" );
     try { 
          ender.uploadFunction(file.getCanonicalPath());
     } catch {...}
```

Comment: Do you have access to a `File` object in your applet?

Comment: yes i do, each file is processed individually, (java.io.File)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are traversing the directory tree that was dragged/dropped and uploading (`put` or `mput` ftp commands) all the files in each subdirectory, you must issue the ftp `mkdir` and `cd` commands to the remote system.

ftp doesn't do sub-trees automatically.

Comment: i ve discovered that the main issue i am having is how can i separate the actual folder strucutre that was dragged eg. level1\level2 from the full path c:\.....\level1\level2

Comment: i m using jsch lib, how do i make sure that the files enter the folder after creating it?

Comment: I don't know / haven't used the JSch lib, but there's [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826821/) about doing sftp with it.