# Executing Shell Scripts from Java Program by ssh to remote server

Tags: java, shell

Below is the program that I am using to ssh to one of the remote servers and its working fine.

**My question is**- Is there any way I can execute the `shell scripts that I have on my windows machine` on the remote server?

If Yes? then how I can modify my below code to execute the shell scripts on the remote server that I am trying to connect.

```
public class SampleTest{
  public static void main(String[] arg){

    try{
      JSch jsch=new JSch();

      String host=null;
      if(arg.length>0){
        host=arg[0];
      }
      else{
        host=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter username@hostname",
                                         System.getProperty("user.name")+
                                         "@lvsaishdc3in0001.lvs.host.com"); 
      }
      String user=host.substring(0, host.indexOf('@'));
      host=host.substring(host.indexOf('@')+1);

      Session session=jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);

      String passwd = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter password");
      session.setPassword(passwd);

      UserInfo ui = new MyUserInfo(){
        public void showMessage(String message){
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
        }
        public boolean promptYesNo(String message){
          Object[] options={ "yes", "no" };
          int foo=JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, 
                                               message,
                                               "Warning", 
                                               JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, 
                                               JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE,
                                               null, options, options[0]);
          return foo==0;
        }

      };

      session.setUserInfo(ui);

      //session.connect();
      session.connect(30000);   // making a connection with timeout.

      Channel channel=session.openChannel("shell");

      // Enable agent-forwarding.
      //((ChannelShell)channel).setAgentForwarding(true);

      channel.setInputStream(System.in);
      /*
      // a hack for MS-DOS prompt on Windows.
      channel.setInputStream(new FilterInputStream(System.in){
          public int read(byte[] b, int off, int len)throws IOException{
            return in.read(b, off, (len>1024?1024:len));
          }
        });
       */

      channel.setOutputStream(System.out);

      /*
      // Choose the pty-type "vt102".
      ((ChannelShell)channel).setPtyType("vt102");
      */

      /*
      // Set environment variable "LANG" as "ja_JP.eucJP".
      ((ChannelShell)channel).setEnv("LANG", "ja_JP.eucJP");
      */

      //channel.connect();
      channel.connect(3*1000);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
      System.out.println(e);
    }
  }

  public static abstract class MyUserInfo
                          implements UserInfo, UIKeyboardInteractive{
    public String getPassword(){ return null; }
    public boolean promptYesNo(String str){ return false; }
    public String getPassphrase(){ return null; }
    public boolean promptPassphrase(String message){ return false; }
    public boolean promptPassword(String message){ return false; }
    public void showMessage(String message){ }
    public String[] promptKeyboardInteractive(String destination,
                                              String name,
                                              String instruction,
                                              String[] prompt,
                                              boolean[] echo){
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can execute the scripts without even copying them to remote server. Invoke a bash shell and pipe the commands from shell script to the remote process ( `bash` in this case ).

So, here is a simple script `echo "Hi there!"; env`. Now we can run this script like this:

```
$ echo 'echo "Hi there!"; env' | ssh localhost bash
tuxdna@localhost's password: 
Hi there!
XDG_SESSION_ID=10
SHELL=/bin/bash
SSH_CLIENT=127.0.0.1 43064 22
USER=tuxdna
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
MAIL=/var/mail/tuxdna
PWD=/home/tuxdna
LANG=en_IN
HOME=/home/tuxdna
SHLVL=2
LANGUAGE=en_IN:en
LOGNAME=tuxdna
SSH_CONNECTION=127.0.0.1 43064 127.0.0.1 22
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
_=/usr/bin/env
```

Essentially you have to write **the shell script** to `STDIN` of **the remote process**.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but probably not in the way you are thinking.

You need to copy the script over to the remote system.

Check out http://seancode.blogspot.com.au/2008/02/jsch-scp-file-in-java.html who's written a `FileSender` wrapper that might help

You could also check out [Copying a file in sftp with jsch library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826821/copying-a-file-in-sftp-with-jsch-library) just out of interest

You could also check out the included examples http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/ (knew they were there somewhere)

Comment: Ok. So that means, the script need to be on remote server to be able to run? Right? if Yes, then I can copy my script to remote server, then is it possible to run that shell script that is there on the remote server?

Comment: Yes and yes.  Copy script to remote, execute script on remote.

Comment: How I can do that using the above program that I have? It will be of great help if you can help me out here with an example related to my code.

Comment: I'd imagine, before you call `Channel channel=session.openChannel("shell");` you'll want to copy the file.  Take a look at some of the links.  The examples that come with jsh are excellent, that's how I worked it out

Comment: Take a look at http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/ScpTo.java.html which is the `secure copy to` implementation